# Angular Material's matTooltip not disappearing after redirecting to another page

Tags: angular, typescript

As title says, the matTooltip doesn't disappear if, let's say, I press a button which has a tooltip attached and redirects me to another page. The tooltip is displayed and it redirects me to the other page, but the tooltip remains visible in the same position. I know that I need to change the "trigger" value from "focus" to "hover", but the solutions I found are all using jQuery. Is there a way I can do this in TypeScript/Angular?

Edit:

This is how my button looks like:

```
  <button type="button"
          #tooltip="matTooltip"
          class="close pull-right cogs-properties"
          matTooltip="Edit button"
          (mouseenter)="tooltip.hide()"
          (click)="onEditPage(page)"
          aria-label="Edit">
    <span class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </button>
```

This is the editPage function:

```
  onEditPage(page) {
    this.selectedPageForEditing = page;
    this.editPageService.sendPage({
      pageName: page["name"],
      templateId: page["value"]["templateId"]
    });
    this.router.navigate([".../page"]);
  }
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview#manually-calling-show-and-hide-), again and again ...

Comment: @trichetriche I already checked the documetation. It still doesn't work...

Comment: Then please provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: material tool tip by default [disappears the moment you click the button](https://stackblitz.com/angular/baprrvoeynl?file=app%2Ftooltip-overview-example.html). what do you mean it "stays" ?

Comment: @Stavm I mean it's still visible on the redirected page at the same position as it was on the initial page. I read about the "trigger" field which value is "focus" by default and it has to be "hover" in order for this to work, but I don't know how can I acces that field without using jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after some deep searches I found that when you're using RouteReuseStrategy with a tooltip (and that's exactly what I'm using), the tooltip doesn't vanish after navigating to another page. For the moment there isn't a fix for this using Typescript/Angular features but only using jQuery. The below links addresses the exactly same problem and offers a solution: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11478#issuecomment-420164916

Comment: My solution is like the [vinothsubramanian's comment](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11478#issuecomment-420213238). If one who wouldn't like to use JQuery to solve it, this is a good solution!

Comment: It should now be working without any problem